# calculate difftime of two time-strings in c?

Tags: c, string, time, time-t

I have a file like this:

```
start 2020-01-13 02:43:39
ende 2020-01-13 02:44:26
start 2020-01-13 02:50:24
ende 2020-01-13 02:50:26
start 2020-01-13 02:50:24
ende 2020-01-13 02:50:26
```

Now Im trying to write a code which calculates the time difference between a start and end time.
This is my code so far.

```
char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    char * command = malloc(MAXCHAR * sizeof(char));

    struct tm result;

    time_t loctime, loc;

    char *buff_date = malloc(30);
    int s=0, e=0;
    while (getline(&line, &len, fp) != -1) { //go trough file and read it line by line
        if(strncmp("start", line, 5) == 0){ //start
            strptime(strncpy(buff_date, line+6, 19), "%c", &result);
            buff_date[19] = '\0';
            s=1; //start command was found
            loc = mktime(&result);

        } else if(strncmp("ende", line, 4) == 0){ //end
            strptime(strncpy(buff_date, line+5, 18), "%c", &result);
            buff_date[19] = '\0';
            e=1; //end command was found
            loctime = mktime(&result);

        }


        if(s == 1 && e == 1){ //I have a command and a start, now calculate diff time
            printf("Difference is  %.2f seconds\n", difftime(loctime, loc)); 
            s = 0;//reset
            e = 0; //reset
        }   
    }
```

My problem is that I always get as result this:

```
Difference is  0.00 seconds
Difference is  0.00 seconds
Difference is  0.00 seconds
```

Can someone help me to find the bug or can someone tell me how I can do this in a better way?

Comment: Why `buff_data[19] = '\0';` ? What is going on at `strptime(strncpy(buff_date, line+6, 19)`? Why not just `strptime(line + 6`?

Comment: `%c` requires time in the preferred format for the locale - are you sure it matches the format of your file? In any event if the file format is fixed, you would not want the parse to be locale specific.  Why not `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`?  `strptime()` returns NULL on a match failure, but you have not checked.

Answer (score 1):

Clear `result` before each `strptime()` call.

```
memset(&result, 0, sizeof result);
result.tm_isdst = -1;   // usually DST flag is unknown in the data just read
strptime(strncpy(buff_date, line+6, 19), "%c", &result);
```

Uninitialized garbage in `result` is messing `localtime()`.

[ref](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html)

> In principle, this function does not initialize tm but stores only
>          the values specified.  This means that tm should be initialized
>          before the call.

---

[@Clifford](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59742812/calculate-difftime-of-two-time-strings-in-c/59743082#comment105634565_59742812) advice is good.  If file data is a fixed format, avoid `"%c"` with its locale dependencies.

---

Improve error checking.  Check results of `strptime(), mktime()`.

---

Minor: use `strncmp("start ", line, 6)` to not incur UB with `strncmp("start", line, 5)` that  occurs when `line` is `"start"` and then `line+6` starts after the string.

Comment: `result` will not be assigned in any event of `strptime()` fails, which it will if the locale time format does not match that used in the file - which is likely.

Comment: @Clifford True - best to check function return values.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Clifford's answer to change two code lines into:
`strptime(strncpy(buff_date, line + 6, 19), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &result);`
`strptime(strncpy(buff_date, line + 5, 19), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &result);`
then you will have a working program (but still without proper error checking).

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica You're right, I corrected my answer